# How do i switch between multiple rtsp video streams without stopping pipeline [gapless streaming]

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm using 5 ip cameras and each of them gives me 5 RTSP streams. I am picking any one of these RTSP video streams and I'm mixing them with my microphones (audio RTSP stream source) and broadcasting it to my RTMP server.

I trying to do gapless streaming meaning there should not be any delay when a camera to camera switch happens. The server should see a continuous stream from my streaming client PC during a camera to camera switch.

I am seeing the pipeline is crashing randomly and giving me lots of error messages. Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Since nobody answered I will give it a shot. When you want to modify your pipeline during playback you will need to do [certain things](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic-pipelines.html) to do so. Also you may want to check the [playout example](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/tests/examples/playout.c) which is doing gapless switching using `compositor` element. What about calling the stuff in pad_probe_cb via g_idle_add() - its suggested in the logs..

Answer (score 0):

To get a true gapless switch you'll need to receive all streams simultaneously into temporary buffers, and then encode the RTMP output off whichever of those buffers is selected.

If you don't do this, you're always going to have a significant delay when doing the switch because you'll have to do a handshake with the encoding hardware and wait for the next keyframe.

It's quite possible to do, it just becomes more of a project than a single stack overflow question...

Comment: it is possible to do it. I am able to do it but i am new facing new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use gstreamer input-selector element to switch between multiple videos and flvmux element to mix single audio source with single video coming from input-selector.

This helped me to achieve my goal. I can see continuous video and audio stream in youtube live broadcast portal using this.

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-input-selector.html

This is the example which helped me to understand and write code for it:

https://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/source/browse/trunk/Main/GStreamer/Source/gst-plugins-base/tests/icles/input-selector-test.c