# How to switch between rtsp streams of an ip camera without disconnecting from the server for fast switching?

Tags: networking, computer-vision, gstreamer, rtsp, ip-camera

Is there any way to switch between different channels (streams) of an IP camera without disconnecting from the RTSP server on the camera? Since the URI of each channel is different using VLC or FFmpeg you need to stop the first channel and then using the URI corresponding to the second channel establish the connection once again and start streaming. This seems to be inefficient and incurs switching delay. I was wondering if there exists any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really avoid the connection step as you need this to get your stream up and running.

What you can do is have multiple streams running in parallel and choose which one to display at a given time.

For example if you just have a small number of streams and the user was likely to switch between each regularly, you could have all the streams connected at the same time, with separate instances of VLC or whatever player you are using, but only display the one you want to the user.

There is a trade off with networking and processing vs fast switching here so this may not work for you and will not really scale beyond a small number of streams.

If you wanted to support a larger number of streams, and the user is likely to navigate in a certain order, e.g. switching from one channel or source to another in order, you could just pre-load and start the next stream in the list to be ready for the change, and again hide it until you want to with over. Similar mechanisms are sometimes used in TV solutions to support fast channel change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. based on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864772/how-do-i-switch-between-multiple-rtsp-video-streams-without-stopping-pipeline-g it seems to be possible, however I am not sure where to start.